# Present or Past in this case?

Tags: grammar

I wonder to use present or past in this case?

If I want to explain to someone and describe the problem.

1/ My car has a problem always that why I can't come on time to work.

2/ My car had a problem always that why I can't come on time to work.

Comment: Does the car have a problem now? Or is it fixed?  Is this a "real" situation or are you using this as an example?  Who are you talking to? Boss? Wife? Friend?  Why are you telling this person this?

Comment: It is an example to learn and  how  and when to use present or past in conversation . not a real . The person is the Boss in the work and he asks me why are you late?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your car still has the problem, you would use the present tense with **has**.

If you car no longer has the problem, you would use the past tense with **had**.

But your examples could be written in better English:

Either:

> My car has a persistent problem; that's why I can't come/get to work on time.

or

> My car had a persistent problem; that's why I couldn't come/get to work on time.

Comment: So if I come to work after fix the problem of the car I should use "had".

Comment: Thanks  for the answer.

Comment: Can I use "always" with has and had.

Comment: Yes, but you would normally place it earlier in the sentence: **My car always has/had a problem......